# How to find a golden dropping fossil?

Tags: fossil-fighters

In Fossil Fighters Frontier, I'm doing a quest for a girl named Daisy. I have to find a golden dropping fossil, and she told me where I can look, but each time I go to the cavern pool (located in a dig site) I can never seem to find it. If anyone knows what I should do, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The Golden Dropping is easily found in Gold Rush Canyon. Go to the service station next to T-rex sue, and go down the metal pathway to the bottom, what is normally a regular fossil dropping will turn into the gold one when you accept this quest.

the metal pathway runs east.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the golden dropping: if you go to Europe, and gain access to the frozen dig site, it's right in there; at least for me anyway.